# What is causing extra height in my amazon store?

Tags: html, css, styling

I am not a css expert, but I added some javascript to a amazon store, On reviewing it was found out that there is some extra space after footer. The management told me that it wasn't there before, I have tried everyting that I know 'firebug' to see what is causing the extra space, but I havn't been successful. The url of the site is http://www.mensgifts4less.com/.
I am attaching a image with the problem[image: See the problem]

I may be asking more, but I am at my wits end. Please help.

Comment: You could add `body div#wrapper{overflow:hidden;}`.

Comment: Thankx @josh crozier, this simple css rule works, mind explaning the details?

Comment: It was because of the "Registered Store" dropdown in the footer.

Comment: Word of advice - refactor scripts. There is too many of them. Not to mention - some of them are useless and blank.

Comment: mouse over menu is getting cropped on NCCA @josh crozier,

Comment: @Ratna ofc it will be cropped. Use another style. Make 2 cols with menu items

Answer (score 1):

1) **Don't use ID for styling, use classes instead**

2) As was mentioned in comments - you need to change overflow-y on wrapper element

```
#wrapper
{
 overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

3) But in your case overflow will cause cropping of menu. Refactor them. Use 2-4 columns if needed. It's just *LI* elements. You can do whatever you want with them. For instanse use 200px width on ul, 100px width on li and float left. Plus some styling ofcourse

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrapper
{
 overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

If you want to hide both the overflow directions then you can go for **overflow:hidden**;